# Codeigniter: 301 redirect URLs from old site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've recently launched a codeigniter website and need to make some 301 redirects from the old site to the new one. They won't work with regex, so, as there are only a few, I can write redirects for each page. However, after hours of Googling/correcting, I still have no joy. The old site's URLs are .html files, wheras my codeigniter URLs are "clean" URLs. Here's my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
   redirect 301 "/index.html" /index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on

    #This is the redirect I've been trying to make work
    RewriteRule ^/about-us.html /index.php?/about-us [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|index\.html|lib|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 

</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(about-us)\.html$ /index.php?/$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Or for redirecting all old `.html` links:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /index.php?/$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on comments, you just need this rule to take care of old URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thats brilliant, thanks! How would I remove index.php from the redirected URL?

Comment: Exactly, so the redirects are the same as the URLs which were not redirected.

Comment: Thanks :) How would I do it if the old .html URL was different to the new URL?

Comment: Then you need specific rules **before above 301 rule**. Like this: `RewriteRule ^foo-bar-baz\.html$ /abc123 [R=301,NC,L]`